# Decoding a ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE string in Android

Tags: java, android, decode, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to decode a string from my vcard

```
ADR;WORK;;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:;Building 723 Room 317;;Auckland;;Private Bag 92019 Auckland;New Zealand
```

into standard text to display on my Android view. I have already parsed the address field with a vCard parser, using the example in http://android-vcard.googlecode.com/hg/examples/ReadExample.java .

I have followed the suggestion [here](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/algorithms-recursion/9185-how-decode-encoding=quoted-printable-encoded-data.html) for decoding:  to use the [codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) library. However, it is still displaying the string as `;Building 723 Room 317;;Auckland;;Private Bag 92019 Auckland;New Zealand` instead of decoding it.

My decoding code:

```
    byte[] byteAddress = address.getBytes();
    String decodedAddress = "";
    try {
        decodedAddress = new String(QuotedPrintableCodec.decodeQuotedPrintable(byteAddress));
    } catch (DecoderException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    TextView textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
    textView4.setText(decodedAddress);
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because a quoted-printable string of `;Building 723 Room 317;;Auckland;;Private Bag 92019 Auckland;New Zealand` is exactly the same as the unencoded string. The semicolons `;` have nothing to do with quoted-printable encoding, instead, `adr` is a structured element that uses semicolons to denote its parts, in this order:

- PO box
- Extended address
- Street address
- Locality (e.g. city)
- Region/state
- Postal/ZIP code
- Country name